Accounts funds error caused loss of money
Last night I bought a coin using solana. After i bought it the transaction went thru but i was left with a message on my account that read error process solana funds. The coin went up in profit and i tried to sell and it said i owned 0 if that coin not allowing me to sell this problem went on for a couple of hours. Eventually the coin tanked before I could get my account running again and i lost all my profit and initial investment. I have pictures to prove of this happening and im wondering if i can get my initial investment back as that seems like a platform error and theres nothing I can do about that, and it left me displeased.
